# Animating text in an Android widget

Tags: android, animation, android-widget

I've been trying to get text to animate in an Android widget. Specifically, I want the text to fade in and out.

I know this is possible, as the Genie News and Weather widget that ships with most Android handsets does it. However, I cannot see how this is done using animators or text switchers (neither of which appear to be supported).

I'm assuming this ISN'T done using alarms, as this seems like total overkill for an animation.

Does anyone know how this is done?

Answer (score 2):

You can use ViewSwitcher or TextSwitcher for that

```
    <TextSwitcher
     android:id="@+id/switcher"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:inAnimation="@android:anim/fade_in"
     android:outAnimation="@android:anim/fade_out" >

     <TextView
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         android:text="Hello" />

     <TextView
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         android:text="World" /> 
  </TextSwitcher>
```

if you call setText on the textSwitcher it will fade out the current text and fade in the new text.

---

you can also start an animation for any View object programatically.

```
Animation fadeIn = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), android.R.anim.fade_in);
textView.startAnimation(fadeIn);
```

Comment: Neither TextSwitcher nor ViewSwitcher is supported by [RemoteViews](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RemoteViews) and you can't use Animation in a widget...

Answer (score 1):

You can use an Alpha Animation, defined in an xml file or programmatically...
Here is the documentation about animations:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/animation-resource.html#alpha-element

When do you want the animation to start?